# how to ask manager to evaluate me as product manager

Tags: manager

I am decently good developer. I have been toying with the idea of becoming a technical program manager/developer for a long time. what has been holding me back is the fear whether i am suited for that role and whether i would succeed. I was wondering about asking my manager's feedback about whether he sees me as a good program/product manager.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is directly:

> Hey boss, Can I have a moment of your time? I wanted your input on how you feel I would be as a product manager. I think this is where I want to take my career but I'm not sure what my strengths and weaknesses in this area would be.

Do it when you will have time to talk. Maybe arrange a follow up.